# How to select multiple Columns in SQL with inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, multiple-columns, entity-relationship

as you can see in my picture i have got an eer-model with 6 tables.
[image]
Now I want from the table "catalog" the "ItemID", from "Users" the "UserID" and from "Roles" the "RoleID" selected in one Table.

[image]

Here is like how my result should look like, just with content

[image]

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions.

Comment: Okay I take a look, I am very new at this.

Comment: Simply  SELECT c.itemid, u.user_id, r.role_id
    FROM roles r 
    JOIN policyuserrole pur ON r.id = pur.roleid
    JOIN users u ON u.userid = pur.userid? You should make more clear what you want to know, please.

Comment: Ich möchte einfach dass ich von den sechs Tabellen die Werte Path, UserName und RoleName im Zusammenhang erhalt. Also z.B. (Path = "Admin", Username = "Gruppe/ABC" und RoleName = "PowerUser")